# Metodo com Parametro jsf + output

Tags: jsf

Como eu consigo passar um parametro para um método e ao mesmo tempo retornar o valor do metodo com output?

Exemplo.

```
//Bean
public String getResposta(String ok){
    return ok;
}

//pagina

<h:outputLabel value="#{bean.resposta('RespostaParaRetornar')}">
```

como eu consigo o mesmo efeito dessa sintaxe no jsf? ou como faço para que ela funcione.
OBS: Não quero passar o parametro em commandButton, necessito dele no outputText ou outPutLabel.

Usando essa sintaxe do exemplo não funciona.

O JSF acusa erro de Sintaxe. e na pagina lança a exception.javax.el.MethodNotFoundException:

Bean Completa.

```
package br.com.so.bean;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

import br.com.so.modelo.Questao;

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class SimuladoRealizadoBean {

    private Map<Long, String> mapaAuxiliar;
    private List<Questao> questoes;
    private String resposta;

    public Map<Long, String> getMapaAuxiliar() {
        return mapaAuxiliar;
    }

    public void setMapaAuxiliar(Map<Long, String> mapaAuxiliar) {
        this.mapaAuxiliar = mapaAuxiliar;
    }

    public List<Questao> getQuestoes() {
        return questoes;
    }

    public void setQuestoes(List<Questao> questoes) {
        this.questoes = questoes;
    }

    public String getResposta(String parametro) {

//      FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
//      Map<String, String> params = facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
//
//      if (params.get("id") != null) {
//          String questaoID = params.get("id");
//          System.out.println(mapaAuxiliar.size());
//          System.out.println(questaoID);
//          if (questaoID != null) {
//              questaoID = questaoID.trim();
//              Long id = Long.parseLong(questaoID);
//              return this.mapaAuxiliar.get(id);
//          }
//      }
//      
//      return null;

        return parametro;
    }

}
```

//XHTML

```
<h:form id="formulario"
            rendered="#{simuladoRealizadoBean.questoes != null}">
            <p:dataList value="#{simuladoRealizadoBean.questoes}" var="q"
                type="unordered" rowIndexVar="qi" itemType="none" paginator="true"
                rows="1" styleClass="paginated">
                <div style="padding: 5px;">
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{q.texto}"
                        styleClass="textoJustificado-centro" />
                    <br />
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{q.referenciaTexto}"
                        style="color:black; float:right; font-size: 12px;" />
                    <br /> <br />
                    <p:outputLabel value="(#{q.disciplina.nome})" />
                    <br /> <br />
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{qi+1}) #{q.enunciado}" style="color:black;" />
                    <br /> <br />
                    <p:outputLabel value="Resposta: #{q.resposta}" style="color:black;" />
                    <br />
                    <h:outputFormat
                        value="Sua Resposta: #{simuladoRealizadoBean.resposta('Parametro')}"
                        style="color:green;">
                        <f:param value="#{q.id}" name="id"></f:param>
                    </h:outputFormat>
                </div>
            </p:dataList>
        </h:form>
```

Comment: Está dando algum erro?

Comment: O JSF acusa erro de Sintaxe. e na pagina lança a exception.javax.el.MethodNotFoundException:

Comment: Coloca sua classe bean completa, tem como?

Comment: Coloquei o Bean e o XHTML.

Comment: parece que ele não ta encontrando seu método, uso o nome inteiro dele( getResposta)

Comment: O Problema é que estou tentando setar e retornar com o metodo GET. De qual forma consigo realizar um efeito parecido com esse e que funcione? eu preciso que o próprio output passe o parametro para o bean e retorne o parametro.

Comment: Apenas com getResposta ele funciona, mas não é isso que preciso, para cada item do DataList ele vai setar um valor e depois retornar algo a partir desse valor. Para ficar mais claro, o 'Parametro' vai ser a questão do dataList  "q.id" a partir desse id ele vai buscar no MAP a resposta que o usuário escolheu e retornar na tela.